# passing NotMapped Property to DropdownList through ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
public class EmployeeDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.FirstName + " " + this.MiddleName + " " + this.LastName).ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

Create Action Method

```
public ActionResult CreateEmploymentType()
{
    PopulateEmployeeIdDropDownList();
    return View();
}
```

Method to populate

```
private void PopulateEmployeeIdDropDownList(object selectedEmployeeId = null) 
{

    var EmployeeIdQuery = from d in db.EmployeeDetails
                  orderby d.FullName
                  select d;

    ViewBag.EmployeeId = new SelectList(EmployeeIdQuery, "EmployeeId", "FullName", selectedEmployeeId);
}
```

View for dropdown list

```
EmployeeName: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.EmployeeId)
```

Problem:

when I run the application it gives error message

> The specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of deferred execution by sending the query to a list:

```
ViewBag.EmployeeId = new SelectList(
    EmployeeIdQuery.ToList(), "EmployeeId", "FullName", selectedEmployeeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with LINQ query, as `FullName` doesn't exists in database LINQ to Entities is unable to generate a query. So set it manually

```
var EmployeeIdQuery = from d in db.EmployeeDetails
              orderby d.FirstName + " " + d.MiddleName + " " + d.LastName
              select d;
```

I also suggest you instead of query pass `Output` of query and remove deferred execution.

```
ViewBag.EmployeeId = new SelectList(
    EmployeeIdQuery.ToList(), "EmployeeId", "FullName", selectedEmployeeId);
```